# Failure to find org.ops4j.pax.cdi:pax-cdi-features:jar:1.0.0.RC1

Tags: apache-karaf, maven-dependency-plugin, pax-exam, ops4j

I was getting following error while running Apache Karaf through Pax-Exam

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.1.5:features-add-to-repository (features-add-to-repository) on project my-project: Error populating repository: Can't resolve artifact org.ops4j.pax.cdi:pax-cdi-features:xml:features:[1.0.0.RC1,2): Failure to find org.ops4j.pax.cdi:pax-cdi-features:xml:features:[1.0.0.RC1,2) in http://x.x.x.x/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR]     mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.ops4j.pax.cdi -DartifactId=pax-cdi-features -Dversion=[1.0.0.RC1,2) -Dclassifier=features -Dpackaging=xml -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR]     mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.ops4j.pax.cdi -DartifactId=pax-cdi-features -Dversion=[1.0.0.RC1,2) -Dclassifier=features -Dpackaging=xml -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
```

so i tried to get it manually with below maven command

```
 mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get 
-DrepoUrl=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots@id=ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy@snapshots@noreleases 
-Dartifact=org.ops4j.pax.cdi:pax-cdi-features:1.0.0
```

but its still giving following error and unable to download it

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Couldn't download artifact
: Failure to find org.ops4j.pax.cdi:pax-cdi-features:jar:1.0.0 in http://x.x.x.x/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, res
olution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR]     mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.ops4j.pax.cdi -DartifactId=pax-cdi-features -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR]     mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.ops4j.pax.cdi -DartifactId=pax-cdi-features -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[ur
l] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   org.ops4j.pax.cdi:pax-cdi-features:jar:1.0.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR]   nexus (http://x.x.x.x/nexus/content/groups/public, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR]   temp (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots@id=ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy@snapshots@noreleases, releases=true, snaps
hots=true)
```

***Update1:***
I found while downloading manually its asking about **maven-downloader-plugin** but i couldnt find this plugin

```
←[1;31mERROR←[m] ←[1;31m  Path to dependency: ←[m
←[1;31mERROR←[m] ←[1;31m       1) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0←[m
←[1;31mERROR←[m] ←[1;31m       2) org.ops4j.pax.cdi:pax-cdi-features:jar:1.0.0.RC2←[m
←[1;31mERROR←[m] ←[1;31m←[m
←[1;31mERROR←[m] ←[1;31m----------←[m
←[1;31mERROR←[m] ←[1;31m1 required artifact is missing.←[m
←[1;31mERROR←[m] ←[1;31m←[m
←[1;31mERROR←[m] ←[1;31mfor artifact: ←[m
←[1;31mERROR←[m] ←[1;31m  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-downloader-plugin:jar:1.0←[m
```

Comment: there's no `org.ops4j.pax.cdi:pax-cdi-features:1.0.0` this artifact is available only with type=`xml` and classifier=`features`.

Comment: But its still now working and asking about maven-downloader-plugin, i think pax-cdi has some configuration issue. As i am running Karaf4.1.5 with Apachecamel 2.20.3, it was giving errror, now i changed it to 2.19.5 its working. but i want to use 2.20.3